# Can these Oktoberfest dishes be reheated without ruining them?

Tags: reheating, german-cuisine

I am hosting an Oktoberfest party tonight and would like to do much of the cooking this morning and just re-heat things before the party for time management purposes. Fortunately, I have a good friend that is a retired executive chef bringing schnitzel, but I am responsible for everything else. Here is what I'd like to make ahead:

- German potato salad
- Beer cheese (for pretzel dipping)
- Beer brats (thinking of grilling early and then heating in the oven)
- Saute peppers and onions as a condiment for brats

Can all of this be successfully reheated without making it awful? If so, what temperature? I have two ovens and can do two different temperatures if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a German (Swabian), I would *never* warm up a potato salad. As the term “Salad” implies, it’s served cold or at room temperature. I may serve a lukewarm potato salad if it’s so fresh that it’s *still* warm, but that would actually be a sign of bad time management, especially as the potato salad is supposed to “soak up” the dressing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The potato salad, and the peppers and onions, are standard steam-tray fare. If you can, make them somewhat ahead of time and keep warm, covered, in a low oven. The brats can be treated likewise, though you won’t maintain the same crackle to the casing; your can re-crisp in a fan assist oven for 5-10 minutes at 200C.

Don’t mess with the preparation instructions for the cheese. It’s the least stable of the four.

Comment: Agreed, but it's also worth noting that at least for the peppers and onions that you're going to want to undercook them initially -- or you risk them softening up so much that they lose any texture that they might have.  (although, it's entirely possible that's the style that you're looking for).  And a crock pot tends to be a good way to hold & serve cheese dips, if you have one, so it doesn't cool off and solidify in whatever it's being served from.